# How to make UILabel backGroundColor seeThrough so the UIView color shows?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a UIView with a backGroundColor scheme to it.
I have UILabel on top of it.
But the UILabel backGroundColor covers up the UIView backGroundColor.

How do I prevent this.  Can I make the backGroundColor for the UILabel seeThrough to let the other color come through but still let the UILabel text show?

thx

Comment: I don't really understand, do you want your UILabel's background to be opaque or translucent ?

Comment: I want the UIView color to show and the UILabel text to show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand it right, you have to set the UILabel's background color to clearcolor like so

```
yourLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is to set the UILabel background to be transparent. To achieve this set the `backgroundColor` property to `[UIColor clearColor]` like this:

```
[myLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

And btw. opaque is what you have now, it means that the UIView color is covered by the label.

Answer (score 2):

You have to set your background color as clearColor, So that you ca observe the same like transparency to the view like

```
 labelObject.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```